# How to redirect a domain to different server's subdomain?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, dns

May this question or relevants asked before but I need to finish this issue properly. So let me explain what i want;
1- I've create and designed a wordpress project my own server subdomain ( eg: xyz.proje.com)

2- I've a domain (eg: www.xyz.com) which bought different company.

3- The project will remain my own server but the domain need to redirect this subdomain.

So how can i do this properly? How can change all xyz.proje.com ( and sub pages etc) links to www.xyz.com  in this project?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you checked   [Create A Network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) in wordpress?

or Edit apache [Virtual Host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#virtualhost)?

```
    Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /www/mainsite
        ServerName www.example.com

        # Other directives here
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /www/subdomain1
        ServerName subdomain1.example.com

        # Other directives here
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /www/subdomain2
        ServerName subdomain2.example.org

        # Other directives here
    </VirtualHost>
```